# How can I iterate through a number of similar elements and change the properties of each in turn?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within my webpage I have a number of regular elements that all share the same structure. These elements contain a span that may be filled with some text, or may be left blank.

These elements start by being hidden using JQuery's `hide()` function.

I want to be able to get each element in turn, check whether its child span contains any text, if it does then I want the element to be displayed using `show()`.

Here is an example of the elements I wish to hide/show:

```
<div id="application-number-row" class="row validation-row">
    <div class="col">
        <span>Application Number</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <span id="application-number-value" class="validation-row-value">value</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="property-value" class="row validation-row">
    <div class="col">
        <span>Property Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <span id="property-value-value" class="validation-row-value"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I have the below code. The first function works correctly and hides all of the elements with the `.validation-row` class. The second function however does not work and I'm unsure how to structure my code so that it iterates over each `.validation-row` in turn.

```
function hideAllDataRows() {
    $('.validation-row').hide();
}

function displayPopualtedDataRows() {

    var validationRow = $('.validation-row');

    if (validationRow.find('.validation-row-value').html != "") {
        validationRow.show();
    }
}
```

Here is a breakdown of what I want to happen:

1. Get each .validation-row found in the HTML document
2. Iterate through each .validation-row and check if the child .validation-row-value `<span>` contains any text.
3. If it does, call `$(show())` on the entire `.validation-row`

Comment: I mean you wrote what you want to do at the end, just convert it to code?

Comment: You need to use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 1):

> Get each `.validation-row` found in the HTML document

```
var rows = $(".validation-row");
```

> Iterate through each `.validation-row` and check if the child .validation-row-value  contains any text.

don't need to 'get' them first, but if it helps:

```
var rows = $(".validation-row");
rows.each(function() { 
    if ($(this).find("span.validation-row-value").text() !== "") {
    }
});
```

> If it does, call `$(show())` on the entire `.validation-row`

```
var rows = $(".validation-row");
rows.each(function() { 
    if ($(this).find("span.validation-row-value").text() !== "")
        $(this).show();
});
```

Can streamline this using `.map` or `:contains`

Comment: @MhluziBhaka yes, minor typo - you could have made that edit :)